# When is the sum of iid random variables also an iid random variable?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

(My statistical knowledge is very limited)

Let $x_1,x_2,…$ be independent and identically distributed (iid) random variables. Is the sum $x_1+x_2+…$ also an iid random variable from the same type of distribution? I.e. say $x_1,x_2,…$ are all normally distributed, is $x_1+x_2+…$ also normally distributed?

Comment: What would it even _mean_ to say $X=x_1+\dots$ is iid?

Comment: I love the downvotes!

Comment: If the $x_i$ are i.i.d normally distributed  then their sum will be normally distributed but not independently, and usually not with the same mean and variance as the individual $x_i$ so not identically distributed

Comment: @Henry , so as a first approximation, is it reasonable to assume that whenever you sum random iid variables the resulting variable will be distributed in the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. let's take $X_1,X_2$ as a random sample from $X$. Is $Y=X_1+X_2$ independent from $X_1$? No, obviously
2. Does $Y$ have the same distributio as $X_1$? No, again

let $X_1,X_2$ be iid uniformly distributed in $(0;1)$ then $Y$ is triangular.

$$f_Y(y)=[1-|1-y|]\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(0;2)}(y)$$

That is,

$$ f_Y(y) =
\begin{cases}
y,  & \text{if $0\leq y<1$} \\
2-y, & \text{if $1\leq y<2$}\\
0, & \text{elsewhere}\\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks! What does the bold 1 mean?

Comment: @FriendlyLagrangian : just the indicator function which indicates the support

Comment: @FriendlyLagrangian : added an equivalent definition for $f(y)$